# Помогите сделать ссылку на объект.grouper

Tags: python, django

Имеется

```
# views.py
    def show(request, show_id=1):
        return render_to_response('app_shows_and_times/show.html',
                                {'show': Show.objects.get(id=show_id),
                                'showtimes': Showtime.objects.filter(showtime_show_id=show_id)})
```

который отдает 'showtimes' с такими полями

```
#  models.py
    class Showtime(models.Model):
        showtime_dates = models.CharField('Date', max_length=30)
        showtime_times = models.CharField('Time', max_length=30)
        showtime_format = models.CharField('Format', max_length=4, blank=True)
        showtime_buy_ticket_url = models.URLField('Buy ticket URL', max_length=255, blank=True)

        showtime_started_in_cinema = models.DateField("Show's 1st appearance in cinema", auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        showtime_is_archived = models.BooleanField('No more show in country?', default=False)

        showtime_place = models.ForeignKey('app_places.place', verbose_name='Place')
        showtime_show = models.ForeignKey(Show, verbose_name='Show name')
```

В show.html на данный момент есть такой код, в котором содержится суть проблемы.

```
   {% regroup showtimes by showtime_place as cinema_places %}
    <ul>
        {% for cinema in cinema_places %}
            <li>
# Из {{ cinema.grouper }} я хочу сделать ссылку, 
# но  {{ showtime_place}} я могу получить только из цикла ниже {% for time in date.list %},
# так как в data.list находятся данные всех полей, если я правильно понимаю
                <a href="cinema/{{ showtime_place}}">{{ cinema.grouper }}</a> 
                <ul>
                    {% regroup cinema.list by showtime_dates as cinema_dates %}
                    {% for date in cinema_dates %}
                        <li>
                            {{ date.grouper }}
                            <ul>
                                {% for time in date.list %} # тут находятся данные всех полей, если я правильно понимаю
                                    <li>
                                        {{ time.showtime_times }}
                                    </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Еще раз о проблеме:
Объединяю данные по "названию кинотеатра", но так же хочу "название кинотеатра" сделать ссылкой на подробное описание "кинотеатра". Не могу же я из цикла {% for time in date.list %} вытянуть чтото вроде time.showtime_place, чтоб подставить в  выше по дереву. Подскажите, как правильно решить дилемму?

Вид отрендереного кода (хочу сделать линк на название кинотеатров):
[image: вид отрендереного кода]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cinema.grouper` является экземпляром вашей модели `app_places.place`, со всеми полями, а не строкой. Соответственно ссылку построить не должно быть проблемой.
Например, если в модели кинотеатра есть метод [get_absoulte_url](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/models/instances.html#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url), то ссылку можно получить так – `{{ cinema.grouper.get_absolute_url }}`.